# alternate row style with $index binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am having trouble getting an alternate-row css class applied to a knockout template with a foreach binding context.  I am using knockout 2.1 with the available `$index` context variable.

This is whats confusing:

My Template

```
<li class="row" data-bind="css: { alt: $index%2 }"></li>
```

results in no `alt` classes being applied, however:

```
<li class="row" data-bind="text: $index"></li>
```

works properly and displays the row number.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I struggled with this for a couple minutes and found that this question hadn't really been covered since the new [binding context variables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) (like `$index`)had been introduced in knockout 2.1

The mistake I was making was that I simply forgot that `$index` itself is an observable, and must be unwrapped if we are using it in an expression in the data-bind attribute.  ie,

```
<li class="row" data-bind="css: { alt: $index%2 }"></li>
```

should become

```
<li class="row" data-bind="css: { alt: $index()%2 }"></li>
```

woops :)

Comment: Was just about to ask and then found your answer! Thanks :)

Comment: I was about to go crazy on this one.

Comment: This was frustrating me for a while, thanks for the post!  I didn't realise index was an observable.

Answer (score 12):

Don't do alternate row styling with Javascript, use CSS which is way more efficient :)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: While I do agree with you, if you are trying to support < IE9.0, this pseudo-selector is not available. nevertheless, this question is mainly here to help people understand that the `$index` context variable is itself an observable.  cheers :)

Comment: both of these answers have value.  depending on context, there are many reasons to use one or the other and it's good to see both of these options here and it makes this question a good resource.  this is exactly how stack overflow was intended to work.