# Alternation classes with Knockout.JS

Tags: knockout.js

I have the next table:

```
  <table class="table" id="calls_table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="round-bg header">Val1</th>
            <th class="rep-bg header">Val2</th>
            <th class="rep-bg header">Val3</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="template: {name: 'call-template', foreach: calls}">
        </tbody>

    </table> 

    <script type="text/html" id="call-template">
        <tr class="alt">
            <td><a data-bind="attr: {href: url}, text: v1" class="simp" href=""></a></td>
            <td><a data-bind="attr: {href: url}, text: v2" class="simp" href=""></a></td>
            <td data-bind="text: v3"></td>

        </tr>
    </script>
```

The question is how to add the alternation of classes for TR's? Like: class='alt', class='' -- please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is answered here on SO at [alternate row style with $index binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231256/alternate-row-style-with-index-binding)

I put together a working sample at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/Yr7gQ/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also the jQuery :odd or :even selectors.

```
$(".table tr:even").addClass('alt');
```

This doesn't use knockout to solve the answer, I know, but sometimes simple is good.

Comment: When building tables with KO, this works the first time the table is rendered.  But if you do anything that causes the table to be re-rendered (e.g., change any value), you have to make sure that you call this again.

Comment: photo_tom, yes, that's true as well. Thanks for catching that.